# How do you UNLOAD data to S3 from Redshift in AWS Pipeline and include a date in the filename

Tags: sql, date, amazon-redshift, aws-pipeline

I have a database table on Redshift I want to UNLOAD to S3 each month [through AWS Pipeline]. I have this code that works, but ideally I'd like to add in the current month to the filename too

```
UNLOAD ('
select  *
from reportingsandbox.tmp_test


')
TO 's3://reporting-team-bucket/importfiles/test_123.csv' CREDENTIALS             'aws_access_key_id=123456678;aws_secret_access_key=abcdefg' 
ALLOWOVERWRITE
delimiter ',' 
PARALLEL OFF ;
```

I've tried this to add in the month, but it has not worked, do you know if it is possible?

Thanks

```
's3://reporting-team-bucket/importfiles/test_123{month(myDateTime)}.csv'
```

Comment: This is related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36616796/amazon-redshift-unload-to-s3-dynamic-s3-file-name which suggests that it cannot be done inside Redshift, but instead you'll need for whatever system is kicking off the query to do the string interpolation itself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I worked it out [in aws data pipeline]!

```
's3://reporting-team-bucket/importfiles/test_123-#{format(@scheduledStartTime,'YYYY-MM-dd-HH')}.csv'
```

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to accept your own anwer, that way anyone else will know that your question got resolved.

Comment: It is not working when I perform unload activity from SQLWorkbenchJ. What RS client you are using?

Comment: This has a syntax error, with single quotes inside single quotes.

Comment: Soup_boy, this was from within AWS Pipeline, it runs as a scheduled job

Comment: @ewan123uk would you be willing to share the datapipeline template?

Comment: @John I'm not sure how to export a template, but I use an SQLActivity. The resource is runs on is an ec2 instance, and uses a schedule which has a parameter Start Date Time. I'm pretty sure this parameter is the key, as this is what  this picks up: _test_123-#{format(@scheduledStartTime,'YYYY-MM-dd-HH')}_

Comment: @john this is the unload statement `UNLOAD (' select * from reportinglongterm.test ') TO 's3://test/test-#{format(@scheduledStartTime,'YYYY-MM-dd-HH'‌​)}.csv' CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=12345;aws_secret_access_key=abcde' ALLOWOVERWRITE delimiter ',' PARALLEL OFF gzip ;`